# Why is it wrong to access GUI elements from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface

In every GUI library I've used (Swing, Android, Windows Forms, WPF) there's this golden rule saying that one cannot access or modify GUI elements from another thread (other than the GUI thread). I suppose this rule applies to any GUI library. Breaking this rule will most likely cause application to crash. However, I've been wondering recently, why is it so? I couldn't find any profound explanation. **So what is the low-level explanation of this rule?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of those you listed, some may be wrappers around existing mechanisms, so you have to answer the question indirectly via the underlying GUI framework. In case of multi-platform GUI frameworks like e.g. Qt, you will also have the lowest-common denominator that determines what is possible and what isn't.

Now, why is access to the GUI not thread-safe? In the cases where I'm most familiar with (win32 and X11), accesses are often performed indirectly by sending requests and sometimes waiting for the according answer. This usually works in an atomic way, even across process boundaries, so that is not directly cause of the problem. However, if you do so from multiple threads, the worst that can happen is that data is modified in an uncoordinated way. For example, if you read, modify and write the same widget from two threads, these operations might be interleaved, so that only one thread's modifications will actually be applied.

There are other reasons for not supporting cross-thread access:

- In win32, the queue with the messages is thread-local, which means that only the thread that created a window will actually find and be able to handle messages for that window. I guess this a legacy from times where processes were single-threaded and the message queue was simply a global. Making it thread-local is the same approach as the one used for making `errno` thread-safe.
- Another reason is that support objects are created inside a process that represent some GUI element. For example, the MFC (on top of win32) use a map from the OS' widget handle to a C++ object representing that object. That map is stored in thread-local storage (which follows the thread-local message queue) and the access to the C++ objects is not guarded by a mutex. Accessing these objects from different threads is bad, not because they represent GUI objects but because they are not synchronized, simple as that.
- If you think about modifying the structure of a widget tree (like e.g. the DOM tree in a browser), you either have very detailed knowledge of what other parts of the application are doing or you need to lock access to the whole tree before every operation just to be safe. Needless to say, this effectively prevents any parallel operations, so you can also take the next step and *require* all operations to come from one thread and thus save the whole multithreading overhead.

That said, I believe that Qt and C# (and probably others) actually do support some cross-thread operations. They will work some (more or less obscure) magic that forwards the calls to the GUI thread and forwards the results back to the calling thread again. In other words, they try to make the necessary inter-thread communication more convenient for the programmer, while retaining the efficiency and simplicity of the single-threaded GUI. This is not restricted to GUI handling though but rather a general approach, only that it is especially important for the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

No piece of software is thread-safe unless it is explicitly designed and build to be so.

A GUI is a complex and stateful beast, making it thread-safe would be 'prohibitively expensive'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple reason for this. Usually UI functions are not thread-safe (as making them thread-safe would pessimize performance).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is simply *not true*: Every object in Java might be accesed concurrently, as far as thread-safe techniques are correctly applied. The fact is that Java Swing objects are mostly not prepared for multithreading, so you'll have to perform external synchronization.

There are several instances in which you *need* several threads to interoperate in a GUI: Games, visual effects, user events...

More information about the GUI and multithreading:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html